# why UIImagePNGRepresentation() return nil? when I try to store a new image

Tags: swift, uiimage, uiimagepngrepresentation

I am generating an UIImage of a QR Code, and I want to store it. But when UIImagePNGRepresentation converts the UIImage to Data it always returns nil. please help me!

```
public func generaImagenQR(texto:String)->UIImage?{
    let data = texto.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)
    //Generate a QR code
    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)
        if let output = filter.outputImage?.applying(transform) {
            return UIImage(ciImage: output)
        }
    }
   return nil
}


let imagenDeQR  = generaImagenQR(texto: "hola")

let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imagenDeQR!)
// data == nil !!!
```

Comment: document for `UIImagePNGRepresentation` is "return image as PNG. May return nil if image has no CGImageRef or invalid bitmap format "

Comment: I know, but UIImage has a valid image ( I saw the picture in a view), but it still does not work